Warning in Webpack Build: 'WARNING in ./node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/SSRProvider.mjs' When Importing from react-bootstrap
When I import components from react-bootstrap, I receive the following warning message:
WARNING in ./node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/SSRProvider.mjs
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from C:\Users\avner\Documents\FullStack\AllStar\templates\authentication system\frontend_var2\node_modules@react-aria\ssr\dist\SSRProvider.mjs.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\avner\Documents\FullStack\AllStar\templates\authentication system\frontend_var2\node_modules@react-aria\ssr\dist\SSRProvider.mjs.map'
Here's my code:
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

const MainNavbar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="primary" data-bs-theme="dark" className="text-white">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand as={NavLink} to="/">
          LOGO
        </Navbar.Brand>        
          <Nav className="ms-auto">
            <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/login">
              Login
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/signup">
              Signup
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>      
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default MainNavbar;

However, if I use Bootstrap classes directly (for example, <div className="container">), the message disappears, but then I lose the features of react-bootstrap.
Here's my package.json file:

{
  "name": "react_template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.x",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.
I have tried several approaches to resolve the warning message but none have been successful. Initially, I added the line // eslint-disable-next-line above the import statement of react-bootstrap components like so:
// eslint-disable-next-line
import { Container, Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

However, this did not help in eliminating the warning. Additionally, I completely removed the react-bootstrap package and reinstalled it, but the issue persisted. I even tried rewriting the entire project from scratch hoping it might resolve any hidden issues, but unfortunately, that didn't work either. I have also searched extensively online for a solution, particularly for cases where the error is triggered by importing components from react-bootstrap, but I have not found any solutions that address this specific scenario.
What I expected was that one of these methods would resolve the warning, but what actually happened was that the warning continued to appear regardless of the measures taken.

I also had a similar problem. I think there is a problem with import.
I think it can be solved by writing it line by line using the import method provided on the react-bootstrap homepage.
I hope you give it a try
// import {Button, Navbar, Container, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'

